# Vlookup to retrieve the whole row instead of one cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a problem with the code below that matches first column in 2 sheets using vlookup then copies data from first to second but I instead of copying all data in the row it only copies the first cells next to the matched column. I have no idea where the problem is so every bit of help is really welcomed.

```
Sub solution()

Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim lrow_output As Integer  'variable indicating last fulfilled row
Dim WB_Input As Workbook
Dim WB_Output As Workbook
Dim WS_Input As Worksheet
Dim WS_Output As Worksheet
Dim funcStr As String

Set WB_Input = Workbooks("input")
Set WB_Output = Workbooks("output1")

Set WS_Input = WB_Input.Worksheets("input")
Set WS_Output = WB_Output.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS_Output
    lrow_output = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With WS_Input
    funcStr = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & "'[" & WB_Input.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(2)).Address & ",2,0),"""")"
End With


With WS_Output
    .Cells(1, 2).Formula = funcStr
    .Cells(1, 2).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    WS_Output.Calculate
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lrow_output, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's just how vlookup works - it only returns one value (column `2` in your case, so the cell next to the lookup column).  If you want more columns from the source sheet then you need to add more formulas in additional columns.

Comment: or use application match to return the correct row then just copy paste the whole row.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, So can I add an array count of let's say 90 columns to get all the cells I need copied?@TimWilliams

Comment: If you're running the latest version of Excel, `XLOOKUP` can return a whole row. Something along the lines of `=XLOOKUP("x",A:A,B:Z)`